# useEffect ignoring function call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to fetch new data using `getJobs()` when the `currentFilter` changes. It skips the function call, only the "Filters changed" text appears on the console of my browser and no new state was set on `currentJobs`

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log("Filters changed");
   getJobs(currentFilters).then((jobResponse) => {
      console.log("Fetching data");
      setCurrentJobs(jobResponse.data);
   }).catch(() => {});
}, [currentFilters]);
```

Edit: Added catch() but error still occurs

JSX

```
<JobBoardSearchBar filters={currentFilters} onFilterChange={(f) => navigateWithUpdatedFilters(f)} />
```

```
const navigateWithUpdatedFilters = (filters: JobBoardFilters) => {
   setCurrentFilters(filters);
};
```

Tried to console log the output of the getJobs() line and I get this

```
Promise {<pending>}
  [[Prototype]]: Promise
  [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
  [[PromiseResult]]: undefined
```

Comment: Can you add a `catch` after your `then` to see if an error is intercepted ?

Comment: It still skips `getJobs()`

Comment: You'll need to add more of your code for us to t/s this, right now it looks fine.  How many times are you seeing the `console.log("Filters changed")` pop up?  Does it fire anytime you manually change the filters?

Comment: Okay I added some code, hope that helps

Comment: The "Filters changed" text appears once every time I change something on the filters

Comment: maybe you can check your network request to make sure if your api call really executed

Comment: Thanks for the idea, you are right, api call is failing. Thanks!